# Cannot debug the value of MM_COUNTRY_CODE variable from maxminddb module

Tags: apache, maxmind

This is my apache version:

```
apache2# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 12 2019 14:00:2
```

and this is my configuration:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

Header unset Server
Header unset Bobo-Exception-Type
Header unset Bobo-Exception-Value
Header unset Bobo-Exception-File
Header unset Bobo-Exception-Type
Header unset Bobo-Exception-Line

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"

Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https: data:; frame-src http: data:; upgrade-insecure-requests"

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin ***@***
  ServerName ***.eu
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://plone:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/***.eu:443/mysite/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [P,L]
  Include /dev/null

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(PUT|DELETE|PROPFIND|OPTIONS|TRACE|PROPFIND|PROPPATCH|MKCOL|COPY|MOVE|LOCK|UNLOCK)$
  RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache.log

    <Proxy "*">
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    SSLProxyEngine On

       MaxMindDBEnable On
       MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
       MaxMindDBEnv   MM_COUNTRY_CODE   COUNTRY_DB/country/iso_code
       #MaxMindDBEnv   MM_COUNTRY_CODE   HU

   <LocationMatch />
          #SetEnv TESTVAR HU
          #Header set countrytest %{TESTVAR}e
          Header set countrytest %{MM_COUNTRY_CODE}e
   </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to debug the value of MM_COUNTRY_CODE variable with no success. I tried multiple ways and I receive (null) or simply the name of the variable. I also tried to put it in the logs (as here) and it didn't work.

Can you suggest me how to debug this variable, to get its value, please?

([The docs for geoblocking I follow.](https://github.com/maxmind/mod_maxminddb#blocking-by-country))

Comment: Note: `SetEnv TESTVAR HU` is working - the header is set in this case. Also, `MaxMindDBEnv   MM_COUNTRY_CODE   HU` is not working, so the problem is not accessing the database.